# How to tell typescript, that process is not undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

In the following line of code:

```
internalWhiteList = process.env.INTERNAL_IP_WHITELIST.split( ',' )
```

I get an error saying, `Object is possibly undefined`. `env` variables are loaded into `process.env` using the module named [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) from `.env` file placed at the root.

How could I tell typescript, that `process` is not undefined?
Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
    {
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "outDir": "../dist",
        "allowJs": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noEmitOnError": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "pretty": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "listFiles": false,
        "listEmittedFiles": false
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "test/",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Compile for node as the target?

Comment: @Bergi I am compiling with `esnext` as the target. Updated my question.

Comment: Looks like you need node `typings`. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9466

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Maybe with a [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) (`!`):

```
internalWhiteList = process.env.INTERNAL_IP_WHITELIST!.split( ',' )
```

Or with a `if` statement:

```
if (process.env.INTERNAL_IP_WHITELIST)
  internalWhiteList = process.env.INTERNAL_IP_WHITELIST.split( ',' )
```

> What does it mean???

If you look at the type-defs for Node you see:

```
export interface ProcessEnv {
    [key: string]: string | undefined;
}
```

It's that `string | undefined` that means `INTERNAL_IP_WHITELIST` is possibly undefined, in which case `undefined.split()` is an error, so you need to assert or guard against it being undefined (as this answer demonstrates).

Comment: @Jatt I edited to add the link: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator . Your error _"Object is possibly undefined"_ is not about `process`. But `process.env.INTERNAL_IP_WHITELIST` could be a `string` or `undefined`.

Comment: @Jatt I added an explanation in the answer (it wouldn't fit in comment). Paleo feel free to edit.